Disable Icosphere
I had two meshes imported into Blender. I corrected their vertex groups and weights, exported and imported them into the game. I launched the game and everything was ok, but I needed one more minor fix. So, I exited the game and got a BSOD a while later. When I restarted the computer and loaded the above mentioned mesh into Blender, the Armature looks like in the screenshot and it's flipped 90 degrees and there is also an extra collection with the object "Icosphere".
I never had something like this before and now this "Icosphere" object is added whenever I import .glb into Blender. If I remove this "Icosphere" object, Blender doesn't want to export my mesh and throws an error: "Object 'Icosphere.001' can't be selected because it is not in View Layer 'ViewLayer'!".
How do I get rid of this?


Can you please add your .blend file using BlendExchange?
